# javaScript - popup window in new tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem hope anyone here will help me!

Could someone please help me to edit this javascript code?

The problem is when I enter to the page that has this code, the pop up window starts automatically. Is it possible to do it manually by creating a button that starts and pauses the pop up in the new tab? Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timer = '<?=$timer;?>';
view_go = true;
function start() {
    if (view_go) {
        if (timer > 1) {
            timer = timer - 1;
            $("#seconds").html(timer);
            setTimeout("start();", 1000);
        } else {
            $("#seconds").html("0");
            var response = '<?=$site2['id'];?>';
            var userid = "<?=$data['id'];?>";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "earn-traffic-completed.php",
                data: "site=" + response + "&user=" + userid,
                success: function(msg) {
                    refreshpage();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
view_go = true;
function play() {
    if (!view_go) {
        view_go = true;
        start();
    }
    return false;
}
function pause() {
    if (view_go) {
        view_go = false;
    }
    return false;
}
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("<?=$url;?>", "<?=$site['name'];?>", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width=800,height=600, top=100, left=400,"); 
}

openWin();

var timing = setInterval(function() {   
    if(myWindow.closed) {  
        clearInterval(timing);  
        window.location = '<?=$site['url'];?>/index.php';  
    }  
}, 1000); 

setTimeout(function() {
    if (!myWindow || myWindow.closed || myWindow.closed === "undefined" || myWindow === "undefined" || parseInt(myWindow.innerWidth, 10) === 0 || myWindow.document.documentElement.clientWidth !== 800 || myWindow.document.documentElement.clientHeight !== 600) {
        alert("ERROR! - Please enable popups and then refresh the page.");
        pause();
    }
}, 1000);
function closeWin() {
    if (myWindow) {
        myWindow.close();
        pause();
    }
}
checkWin();
function checkWin() {
    if (!myWindow) {
        alert('ERROR! - Please enable popups and then refresh the page.');
        pause();
        setTimeout("checkWin();", 10);
    }
    if (myWindow.closed) {
        pause();
        setTimeout("checkWin();", 10);
    } else {
        setTimeout("checkWin();", 10);
    }
}
start();
       function refreshpage()
        {

            window.location = document.location.href;
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code remove the call to `openWin();` which you have just after the `openWin` function is declared.

Add a button to your html for example:

```
<button id="openWinButton">Open Window</button>
```

Add the following javascript in place of the call to `openWin()` which adds click event listener to the button, when the button is click the handler function calls your `openWin` function

```
document.getElementById('openWinButton').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action of the triggering element
    openWin(); // call your method to open the window
});
```

Comment: The timer stop and even if i click button to open pop up, the countdown not work. please check my JavaScript and tell me how I can add button to pause and  open popup in new tab. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please, is there any way to open it in new tab?

Comment: @Johnrocks where you have the window.open line, the 2nd argument is currently a string, with a value inserted from what looks like PHP, replace it with `"_blank"`, IE: `window.open("<?=$url;?>", "_blank", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width=800,height=600, top=100, left=400,");`  although it will be up dependant on the settings on the users browser as to whether it opens a window or tab.

Comment: @Rob: Doesn't work, the new tab does not opened. Is there another solution?

Comment: @Johnrocks Like i said it's dependant on the browser settings, you as a website author have no control over whether it opens a window or tab.

Comment: @Rob: There is no settings. if you like, I can post html code here. Does it help? Thank you.